# package import error in command line but not in PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm

I have a project which i was compiling via PyCharm so far. It has a structure like so

```
ParentFolder\
- Mains\
  - __init__.py
  - main.py
- package\
  - __init__.py
  - util.py
```

in main.py I had an import line like so:

```
from package.util import ...
```

Now when I run this in PyCharm, it works without any issues.
However, when I try to run this via the command line, I am unable to import from util.py and I get the error

```
No module named ...
```

Looks like PyCharm is doing something extra, beyond a simply `python main.py` command. Any pointers on what could that be and how I should I replicate it via command line?

Comment: Pycharm adds the current project's directory to `sys.path` (which is where python looks for modules), which is why you can find that module in PyCharm but not when executing directly from the python interpreter.

Answer (score 2):

You can check the configuration you run, and you will find two check boxs checked by default:

```
Add content roots to PYTHONPATH

Add source roots to PYTHONPATH
```

That makes you possible to `import package`.

Comment: That's right. But how should I achieve the same effect via the terminal?

Comment: You can manually set env variable `PYTHONPATH`. For example: `PYTHONPATH=/path/to/your/project python main.py`